# api.ai html integration issue - android webview

Tags: android, webview, webkit

Hy

I need some help

I developed a simple webview android and ios app where i load this html code from the asset https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/Api-AI-Personal-Assistant-Demo/blob/master/index.html

the strange is that in the ios webview is working fine, but in the android version the text response is not displayed, any idea?

ps. the java script is and the dom storage is  enabled

thank you!

Comment: How are you enabling the JavaScript? Could we see your `WebView` initialisation code?